# How to creat graphs/plots in Drupal, using python library matplotlib, updated in real time if possible?

Tags: views, charts

I would like to display plots and graphs in Drupal nodes.

Can somebody point out a good workflow to get this done?

Ideally, I would like to use the graphical python library **matplotlib**. But a solution that is more Drupalish would be fine too.

Ideally, I would like to enter numeric values in an interface, and see a graph updated in **real time**. I have not been able to discover any module(s) for this.

Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution for this. You probably already found the [Charts module](http://drupal.org/node/233753), but that does not seem to support on the fly updates.

So you would need to create your own module. You could then send your data with an ajax call and redraw the graph using that data  (the form api in Drupal 7 has excellent support for this; create a fieldset with its own div in which you put the graph). I'm working with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) (which I really like) in my own modules and do something similar.

Comment: Interesting reply (thanks for the "Charts" suggestion ... I'm its maintainer). I'd be interested in learning more about that ajax-part in your "own modules". Are there any contrib modules among them to look at?